# Why doesn't array work by using fork() function?

Tags: c, process, fork

I try to solve the question.

Question is that

I should creat a process creating child process.

Child process should write 1 to 10 to the int array size of 10 
{ initial value of 0 }.

Mother process should wait until the child done writing.
AFter the child process finishes, the mother process print out the array ( ex. 1,2,...,10) and replace all to -1 and print out the array one more time.

Child is a producer and Mother is a consumer. ( Only one child and Only one consumer. and they do this only once.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
int arr[10]={0,};
pid_t pid;
int state;
pid = fork();

if(pid == -1) // error
{
    printf("can't fork, error\n");
    exit(-1);
}

else if (pid == 0) // Child ( producer )
{
    printf("\nProducer is created.\n");

    printf("array: ");
    for(c=0; c<10; c++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[c]);
        arr[c]=c+1;
    }

}

else // Mother ( consumer )
{
    pid=wait(&state);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\nConsumer takes control of array");


    printf("\narray:");

    for(j=0;j<10;j++) 
    {
        printf(" %d", arr[j]);
    }


    printf("\nConsumer is done.");

    printf("\narray: ");
    for ( i =0; i<10; i++)
    {

        arr[i]=-1;
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);


    }
    printf("\ndone\n");
    exit(0);
}
return 0;}
```

I want output

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

but

my out put is

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

what's the problem with my code?

Comment: When `fork()` creates a child process (successfully) then every existing data of process in memory is duplicated. (Actually, the OS optimizes this as described in the answer but you can imagine it like duplicated.) Thus, you have the surprising effect that what's one variable in your source code becomes two independent variables in `fork()`. Thereby, the child process may not write into the variables of the parent process although the have "the same name". Either use file I/O, pipes, or shared memory for communication between child and parent process.

Comment: In your producer you are printing before changing the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory address spaces of the processes will "copy on write". So the array is not shared between the two processes.

Comment: Could you tell me the solution..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share substantial data between different processes (like parent and child), there are a number of ways. Three of the most common are

1. Producer writes to a file; Consumer reads the file
2. Shared Memory, as provided by the `shm*` API of the Unix kernel
3. Memory mapped files, as provided by the `mmap` API of the Unix kernel

Suggestion: read everything you can find by the late great W. Richard Stevens, such as *Programming in the Unix Environment*.

Comment: I have no time to read the book... How can I share the memory in one code file...

Comment: Do you have time to read the man pages for mmap(2) or shm_open(2)?